# Passing a structure JSON object through state-machines

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to pass a structured json object as a response in case an error occurs but I get

```
  {"errorMessage": {
    "Error": "object",
    "Cause": "{\"errorType\":\"object\",\"errorMessage\":\"[object Object]\",\"trace\":[]}"
  }}
```

in another lambda when passed through state-machine.
So I have to stringify it to received in required format as mentioned below and parse it to get desired value.

```
  const errorLog = {
    line_number: lineNumber,
    error: error.cause.message
  };

  throw JSON.stringify(errorLog);
```

Is it possible to configure the state-machine to pass the structured json object without stringifying it so I can get the desired values?

Structure of my state-machine

```
  Lambda1:
    Type: Task
    Resource:
      Fn::GetAtt: [Lambda1, Arn]
    Catch:
      - ErrorEquals:
          - States.TaskFailed
        ResultPath: $.errorMessage
        Next: Lambda2
  Lambda2:
    Type: Task
    Resource:
      Fn::GetAtt: [Lambda2, Arn]
    Parameters:
      input.$: "$"
```